# Tab content not flexing correctly

Tags: angularjs-material

I am testing this in IE 11:

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/wdshannon/pen/grgXRa)

I am attempting to have the md-tab-body of my md-tabs control flex to the bottom of the page. I have had to include this css rule to get that somewhat working:

```
#tab-content-0 > div, #tab-content-1 > div, #tab-content-2 > div, #tab-content-3 > div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

If you look at the codepen above, you will see that I get a scroll bar when I do so.  What am I doing wrong?  I want the tab content to flex to the bottom of the page, the first interior container to just take up however much space it needs  and the second interior container to flex to the bottom of the tab content, and if it needs more space, it should have a scrollbar inside.

How do I accomplish this?  I think the issue has something to do with the CSS rule above, but I cannot get it to flex at all without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chekc out this pen. I am sure you can do the styling as you did in the other tabs. For this example I just used simple `md-tab` with `label` and other simplified elements.

http://codepen.io/next1/pen/qZRpEB

Comment: Do you think that the more complex tab layout elements are what caused the issue?

Comment: Nope. I guess your custme `css` class caused problem plus you used nested container elements which I didn't understand. So I created on my own way. Do you want me to make the exact tab as you provided?

Comment: No, I think I figured it out.  I guess my nested containers were causing the issue.  Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: No Problem at all :)